# How do I calculate an Average for each value that has a duplicate in a list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates, average

I am struggling to write a function that would go over a list of numbers `[2, 4, 3, 2, 2]` and recalculate the values of duplicates so that all the 2's in this example will sum together(=6) and then will be divided by the length of the list. Length = 5.
Output: `[6/5, 4, 3, 6/5, 6/5]`

Each number has to stay in it's place, and numbers in input list could         be positive and negative.
Any ideas on how to approach?

Answer (score 5):

First, let's import `Counter` and define your list:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = [2, 4, 3, 2, 2]
```

Second, we create `ctr`, an instance of `Counter`, that will contain the number of times each element occurs in your list:

```
>>> ctr = Counter(x)
```

Lastly, let's create the new list that you want:

```
>>> [i if ctr[i]==1 else ctr[i]*i/len(x) for i in x]
[1.2, 4, 3, 1.2, 1.2]
```

`i if ctr[i]==1 else ctr[i]*i/len(x)` is a ternary statement.  It evaluates to `i` if `i` appears in `x` only once. Otherwise, it evaluates to `i` times the number of times `i` appears in `x` divided by the length of `x`: `ctr[i]*i/len(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
t = [2, 4, 3, 2, 2]
print [float(i * t.count(i)) / float(len(t)) if t.count(i) > 1 else i for i in t]
```

**Output**:

```
[1.2, 4, 3, 1.2, 1.2]
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. `1 != 6/5`.

Comment: @DyZ. Thanks the math division problems :)

Comment: right one. May be this `Fraction(1.2).limit_denominator()` will help make the answer more specific like OP mentioned . it will gives like `6/5`.

Comment: @VikasDamodar; Thanks that's new learning for me. Did not know limit_denominator existed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group all the elements first

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> k = [(k,len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(sorted(l))]
```

This will give you tuple for each element of list of the format `(element, frequency)`:

```
>>> [(2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

Next create a mapping dict from this list of tuples

```
>>> mapping = dict(k)
>>> mapping 
>>> {2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

Now replace all elements of original list where the value in mapping dict is greater than 1

```
>>> [map[k]*k/len(l) if map[k] > 1 else k for k in l]
>>> [1.2, 4, 3, 1.2, 1.2]
```